# Return a single Element from an Associative Array from a Function

Tags: php, arrays, hash, mapping, array-combine

Lets assume we have two PHP-Arrays:

```
 $some_array = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
 $another_array = array(101,102,103,104,105,106);
```

In PHP, there are already some Array-Functions that allow the construction of an *Associative Array* (AKA hash), e,g,;

```
 $hash = array_combine(
           $some_array,
           $another_array
         );
```

And here it comes. What should I do if I want to create a hash in a more functional style, if I want to compute key and value *on the fly* and build the hash through a map-operation, like (**not working**):

```
 # wishful thinking
 $hash = array_map(
            function($a, $b){ return ($a => $b); },
            $some_array,
            $another_array
         );
```

The problem here seems to be the expectation, the line

```
            ...
            function($a, $b){ return ($a => $b); }
            ...
```

would indeed return **an key value/pair of a hash** - which it doesn't.

Q: How can I return a key/value pair from a function - which can be used to build up an associative array?

---

**Addendum**

To make clear what I really was looking for, I'll provide a perl example of hash generation:

```
 ...
 # we have one array of characters (on which our hash generation is based)

 my @array = qw{ a b c d e f };

 # now *generate* a hash with array contents as keys and 
 # ascii numbers as values in a *single operation *
 # (in Perl, the $_ variable represents the actual array element)

 my %hash = map +($_ => ord $_), @array;
 ...
```

Result (%hash):

```
 a => 97
 b => 98
 c => 99
 d => 100   
 e => 101
 f => 102
```

From the responses, I'd now think this is impossible in PHP. Thanks to all respondends.

---

Comment: hah, maybe you can store the key/value pair in a 2-length array... 

return new array( key, value), perhaps? <i'm not familiar with php>

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. You can use a var to create a key in an array. Given $a and $b, you can do $my_array[$a] = $b;

Comment: mingos, I want to create the array (the hash) at once through a map- or other operation. Something like "array_fill_keys()", but with callback function as in array_map().

Comment: I think I don't understand the question.  I don't see how `array_combine()` is not the exact technique that you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: It's not entirely clear whether you're having a problem merely with returning multiple variables from a function, or whether you're having problems storing a function in an array. Your post gives the impression that storing the function in the array works, so I'll tackle the return-multiple-variables problem.

There is no way to return a single instance of a key/value pair in PHP. You have to have them in an array... but remember that in PHP, an array and hashmap are exactly the same thing. It's weird (and controversial), but that means it's perfectly legitimate to return an array/hashmap with the multiple values you wish to return.

There are only two sane ways that I know (from 10+ years of PHP experience) to get more than one variable out of a function. One is the good'ol fashion way of making the input variable changeable.

```
function vacuumPackSandwitch(&$a, &$b) {
    $a = 505;
    $b = 707;
}
```

This will change both $a and $b as opposed to changing copies of them like usual. For example:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
vacuumPackSandwitch($a, $b);
print $a.' '.$b;
```

This will return "505 707", not "1 2" like normally. You might have to do:

```
vacuumPackSandwitch(&$a, &$b);
```

But if that's the case, the PHP compiler will duly let you know.

The other way is to return an array, which I suppose is the clearer and preferred way.

```
function ($a, $b) {
    return array($a, $b);
}
```

You can grab both variables at the same time by doing:

```
list($c, $d) = vacuumPackSandwitch($a, $b);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Helgi, thank you very much for your comment. You say: "There is no way to return a single instance of a key/value pair in PHP". This is what I already suspected. So I know that from now on ;-) Thanks.

Comment: i think my comment summarized what he said here... :) nvm

Answer (score 2):

In PHP arrays can be associative too! An int-indexed array is just an associative array with 0 => element0 and so on. Thus, you can accomplish what you are looking for like this:

```
$somearray = array('name' => 'test', 'pass' => '***', 'group' => 'admin');

function myfunc($a, $b) { return array($a => $b); }

if($somearray['name'] == 'test') { echo 'it works!'; }

// Let's add more data with the function now
$somearray += myfunc('location', 'internet');

//Test the result
if($somearray['location'] == 'internet') { echo 'it works again!'; }
```

It is really very simple. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi hb2pencil, I tried to make a compact operation (like array_map) based on an array - which produces a list of key/value instances that make up the hash eventually. This is (as it looks now) impossible in PHP. I'll make an addendum to my posting in order to provide an "other-language"-example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question, but google still likes it for a search I recently made, so I'll post my findings. There are two ways to do this that come close to what you're attempting, both relying on the same general idea.

Idea 1:

Instead of returning a key => value pair, we return an array with only one element, 'key => value', for each sequential element of the original arrays. Then, we reduce these arrays, merging at every step.

```
$array = array_map(
    function($a, $b){
        return array($a => $b);
    },
    $arr1,
    $arr2
);
$array = array_reduce(
    $array,
    function($carry, $element){
        $carry = array_merge($carry, $element);
        return $carry;
    },
    array()
);
```

OR

Idea 2:

Similar to idea one, but we do the key => value assignment in array_reduce. We pass NULL to array_map, which creates an array of arrays (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$array = array_map(NULL, $a, $b);
$array = array_reduce(
    $array,
    function($carry, $element){
        $carry[$element[0]] = $element[1];
        return $carry;
    },
    array()
);
```

Personally, I find Idea 2 to be a lot more elegant than Idea 1, though it requires knowing that passing NULL as the function to array_map creates an array of arrays and is therefore somewhat un-intuitive. I just think of it as a precursor to array_reduce, where all the business happens.

Idea 3:

```
$carry = array();
$uselessArray = array_map(
    function($a, $b) use ($carry){
        $carry[$a] = $b;
    },
    $a,
    $b
);
```

Idea 3 is an alternative to Idea 2, but I think it's hackier than Idea 2. We have to use 'use' to jump out of the function's scope, which is pretty ugly and probably contrary to the functional style OP was seeking.

Lets just streamline Idea 2 a little and see how that looks:

Idea 2(b):

```
$array = array_reduce(
    array_map(NULL, $a, $b),
    function($carry, $element){
        $carry[$element[0]] = $element[1];
        return $carry;
    },
    array()
);
```

Yeah, that's nice.